# Getting error 'Operation is not valid due to the current position of the navigator. ' on creating new attribute

Tags: c#, xml

here is my code, when i create an attribute if it is not present:

```
 if (httpRuntime.MoveToAttribute("maxRequestLength", ""))
          httpRuntime.SetValue("2097151");
        else
           httpRuntime.CreateAttribute("", "maxRequestLength", "", "2097151");
```

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current node is not on the element. Move it there first.